# How to Mock a function in Python(Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I don't have any idea what should I mock.

I have a function that takes a 'username' argument and deletes a user from list of users based on the passed 'username' :

```
users = [
    {"username": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com"},
    {"username": "Smith", "email": "Smith@gmail.com"},
]


@app.route("/students/<string:username>", methods=
["DELETE"])
def delete_student(username):
    user = list(filter(lambda x: x["username"] == username, users))
    if user:
        users.remove(user[0])
        return "", 204
    else:
        return "", 404
```

How do I should mock this function?
What do I should mock?

Comment: What is the source of `users`?

Comment: 'users' is just a list of dictionaries. I'll update the code at a moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to patch the function, but the module level dictionary.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.dict('yourmodule.users', {'newkey': 'newvalue'}):
    ... # here goes the test call
```

Comment: Why there is not need? can you please explain a little more.

Comment: The function can stay the same for the test, as the data source is outside of it. I am currently on mobile, if it`s still unclear, I will answer later.

Comment: i would appreciate.

Comment: Hm, so what it unclear to you? You want to test the function, right. In order to test you need to provide input and test whether the output is what you expect. You cannot easily pass in some custom input, as your `users` is at the module level, and not an input parameter. That's why you need to mock the input.